# Fill up advanced custom field of a custom post type via API REST POST

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, rest-api

I have few custom fields created by ACF on a custom post type "room".

I use postman and the REST API to try to create a new room with my custom fields.

The Autorization is ok.
I success to create my room, but all the custom fields are empty.
I'm sending a raw content like this :

```
{
"title":"Sample ACF field demo",
"status": "publish",
"acf": 
    {      
        "title_fields" : "Custom title",  
        "rent_field" : 100,
    }
}
```

Why, the custom fields stay empty ? I'm doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it :

Replace acf by fields

```
{
"title":"Sample ACF field demo",
"status": "publish",
"fields": 
    {      
        "title_fields" : "Custom title",  
        "rent_field" : 100,
    }
}
```